# How to find multiple column number

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm looking to get the column number containing keyword 1, then the column number for keyword 2, etc ...

I found the script to get the number of a one column, but I can't find the solution for multiple keywords

The objective is to find the number of the columns concerned by my scripts to avoid rewriting them if I delete a column in my sheet.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you could do this. This is a sample:

**Sample headers in row 1 on sheet : Data:**

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name | Age | Hobby |

**The script**

```
function headersExample(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  const headers = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn())
    .getValues()
    .flat()
    .reduce((acc, next, i) => {
      acc[next] = i + 1;
      return acc;
    },{})

  console.log(headers);
  console.log(`Column number for Hobby = ${headers["Hobby"]}`);
}
```

**Log 1:**

```
{ Name: 1, Age: 2, Hobby: 3 }
```

**Log 2:**

```
Column number for Hobby = 3
```

Comment: Many thanks RemcoE33 ! My script works now ;)